# pandas dataframe operation (divide multiply) with two different time indices

Tags: python, pandas, divide

Trying to divide a column in one data frame with daily time index over many years by a column of a second data frame which is indexed by day of year.  For example, make a dataframe indexed daily.  Make a second dataframe with the median values by date.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy.random as npr 
    rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=365*5, freq='D')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(npr.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
    df_med = df1.groupby(lambda x: x.dayofyear).median()
```

I would like to divide df1 by df_med so that I generate a dataframe of data normalized by the median value for that day of year.

```
    df_norm = df1.div(df_med, axis=1)
```

This doesn't work, but I'm afraid that I don't know what does.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does this give you what you want: `df1.div(df1.groupby(lambda x: x.dayofyear).transform(pd.Series.median))`?

Comment: Sure does!  Thank you EdChum

Comment: I'll post as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the division didn't work is because the grouped df is a different shape, so one way would be to call [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) so that it returns a series with an index aligned to the original df and then you perform the division:

```
In [165]:

import numpy.random as npr 
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=365*5, freq='D')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(npr.randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
print(df1.info())
df_med = df1.groupby(lambda x: x.dayofyear).median()
df1.div(df1.groupby(lambda x: x.dayofyear).transform(pd.Series.median))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1825 entries, 2010-01-01 to 2014-12-30
Freq: D
Data columns (total 1 columns):
0    1825 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 28.5 KB
None
Out[165]:
                     0
2010-01-01   -0.323354
2010-01-02   -1.148487
2010-01-03   -0.206003
2010-01-04    1.768663
2010-01-05  -25.856032
2010-01-06   10.113401
2010-01-07   -0.754476
2010-01-08    1.271442
2010-01-09   -0.845800
2010-01-10    2.037104
2010-01-11   -7.730482
2010-01-12   10.873351
2010-01-13    0.924056
2010-01-14    1.000000
2010-01-15   -2.764203
2010-01-16    1.205966
2010-01-17    1.775265
2010-01-18    4.983361
2010-01-19  -17.537263
2010-01-20    1.000000
2010-01-21    1.000000
2010-01-22    2.176172
2010-01-23   -2.442958
2010-01-24   -3.126872
2010-01-25   -1.612845
2010-01-26   13.099342
2010-01-27   -1.683263
2010-01-28    1.000000
2010-01-29    0.225677
2010-01-30    7.862236
...                ...
2014-12-01  -71.974731
2014-12-02    1.000000
2014-12-03   -0.975790
2014-12-04   -4.715373
2014-12-05    1.000000
2014-12-06   -1.111680
2014-12-07    0.522016
2014-12-08    3.233062
2014-12-09 -228.056902
2014-12-10    1.342591
2014-12-11  -11.872743
2014-12-12    1.000000
2014-12-13  -75.493044
2014-12-14    0.354384
2014-12-15    0.248133
2014-12-16   -2.483432
2014-12-17    1.000000
2014-12-18   -2.942194
2014-12-19    0.561869
2014-12-20    2.421608
2014-12-21    1.629229
2014-12-22    4.050602
2014-12-23   -1.040709
2014-12-24    1.000000
2014-12-25   -7.681764
2014-12-26    1.032772
2014-12-27   13.222927
2014-12-28   -8.698441
2014-12-29    1.658290
2014-12-30   -0.951775

[1825 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks very much EdChum.  I hadn't used transform before and that is the ticket.  I knew that the 2 df's were different shape, but didn't know a simple way to make them the same.

Comment: No worries generally you can't perform math operations if the other df/series is not broadcastable meaning not the same length/shape. `transform` is specifcally designed for these kind of situations, generally it is used for adding new columns from the groupby operation

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed to understand. I've read a bit about it now and think I can start to use it.